# Read CSV file, modify its content and write to S3 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, amazon-s3, smartercsv

I am trying to read csv file uploaded to s3 server, then modify its content and then write it back to the server. 
For reading i am using the following code..

`object=bucket.objects['test.csv']
    url= object.url_for(:read, :expires => 10*60, :secure => true)
    urlw= object.url_for(:write, :expires => 10*60, :secure => true)
    csv_file  = open(url,'r')
    @dealers = SmarterCSV.process(csv_file)`

Then i want to modify a record and write it back to CSV. How can i achieve this. Also if i want to delete a record.

Comment: You can create a new csv file by programmatically manipulating `@dealers` object - taking care of modifying / deleting individual rows. Later on overwrite the original file with the new one.

Comment: Can you show some example code.